# REGEX replace single character 0

Tags: regex, replace, expression

I have a table with data in it. some data is 0 and I want to replace it with -
    But i also have 0,25 and that has to stay like it is.

```
So :

0 -> -
0,25 -> 0,25
01 -> 01
000001 -> 000001

ONLY single character "0" has to be replaced. How I do this?
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: all of the comments below. none of them worked for me :( still searching.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the single `0's` are followed by a whitespace character, you could simply use a negative lookahead, e.g:

```
0(?!\S)
```

This matches all `0's` which are followed by a whitespace character, you can find an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ls1qTN/1).

Comment: any idea how I can write in EasyCatalog?
It's like REGEX:0(?\S)

Answer (score 0):

- Find: `(?<![\d,])0(?![\d,])`
- replace: `-`

This will replace `0` by `-` only if not preceeded and followed  by a digit or a coma.

Not sure EasyCatalog understand lookarround, but you could try:

```
REGEX:^(?<![\d,])0(?![\d,])=-
```

Another way without lookarround:

```
REGEX:^(^|[^\d,])0([\d,]|$)=$1-$2
```

Comment: how I put it in code? I write like this
REGEX:^^0=-;

Comment: @KevinDelcroix: It depends on which language you're using

Comment: I use it in EasyCatalog (Indesign Plugin) so I have no idea what language it is:

Comment: @KevinDelcroix:I don't know well EasyCatalog but have a try with my edit.

Comment: @KevinDelcroix:I've added another solution, see my edit. And, what error did you get?

Comment: Hey, i tried but it's still not working. I don't get an error he is just not doing anything. the 0 is still there and the 0,25 is still there also. Like nothing changed. Mayby the code is too complex? Another suggestions please?

Comment: @KevinDelcroix:Sorry, I don't see anything more, I don't know easycatalog :(  May be there are some forum dedacated on the easycatalog site.